# String.replaceFirst is not working for parameter with $ symbol

Tags: java, string

I am trying to replace the parameter from the url before doing restTemplate.exchange as below.

```
String userKey = "$$maryann$$";
String resourceURL = 
       "http://api.qal1.net/v3/fis/1234/getCustomer/{value}"                           

resourceURL = resourceURL.replaceFirst("\\{" + "value" + "\\}", userKey);
```

is throwing below error,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference
at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:857)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceFirst(Matcher.java:1004)
at java.lang.String.replaceFirst(String.java:2178)
```

I want the resultant string as

```
http://api.qal1.net/v3/fis/1234/getCustomer/$$maryann$$
```

Could you please assist?

Comment: The problem is that `replaceFirst()` operates on regular expressions and the replacement allows for group references in the form `$groupnumber`. Try to escape the the dollars: `resourceURL.replaceFirst( ..., Matcher.quoteReplacement( userKey ) );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`replaceFirst` is using regular expression (regex) syntax where `$` is special symbol:

- in description of what you want to match (target) it represents end of string,
- in replacement part it can be used to access match from n-th group like `$n`.

So you need to escape it. You can do it manually via `\$` (which in string literal needs to look like `"\\$"` because `\` is also special there), or you can use methods which can escape it for you like

```
str = str.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(yourTarget), Matcher.quoteReplacement(yourReplacement);
```

Comment: Result of this above method is coming as, http://api.qal1.net/v3/fis/1234/getCustomer/{GUID}. I cannot escape $ from $$maryann$$ because it is a userid of an end user and same thing exactly i should pass to API.

Comment: It works fine for me: https://ideone.com/YRZ3P6

Comment: Thanks! I was not assigning a resultant string back to variable. It is working fine now.